# How to declare a string type with a specific prefix

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to declare a string type that has a specific string as a prefix? Similar to this effect:

```
type Path = 'site/' + string;

let path1: Path = 'site/index'; // success
let path2: Path = 'app/index'; // error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't know of a way to achieve this, but it sorta relates to [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) which I've been watching, more specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-417207783). Is this your use case for such type?

Anyway, I suspect we won't get such feature anytime soon, but it might be possible to declare such type statically if [types such as `StringConcat` are introduced to TypeScript as this comment suggests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754#issuecomment-479518403). All I can do is advise you to use `RegExp` in the meanwhile to validate such strings.